# powershell: Append text before specific line instead of after

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm looking for a way to add text before a line.
To be more specific, Before a line and a blank space.
Right now the scripts adds my text after the line [companyusers]. 
But I'd like to add the line before [CompanytoEXT] and before the blank space above [CompanytoEXT].

Does any body know how to do this?

Visual representation of what I'd want to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEbK9.jpg

My current script:

```
$FileName = "C:\temptest\testimport - Copy.txt"
$Pattern = "[[\]]Companyusers"  
$FileOriginal = Get-Content $FileName

[String[]] $FileModified = @() 
Foreach ($Line in $FileOriginal)
{   
    $FileModified += $Line
    if ($Line -match $pattern) 
    {
        #Add Lines after the selected pattern 
        $FileModified += "NEWEMAILADDRESS"

    } 
    }

Set-Content $fileName $FileModified
```

Thanks for any advice!

Even if you're just pointing me where to look for answers it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Based on the helpful images I would say your question is a bit misleading. I think "Insert a line at the end of a specific ini file section" would transport the meaning better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be easier using an `ArrayList`, that way you can insert new data easily at a specific point:

```
$FileName = "C:\temptest\testimport - Copy.txt"
$Pattern = "[[\]]Companyusers"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$file = Get-Content $FileName
$insert = @()

for ($i=0; $i -lt $file.count; $i++) {
  if ($file[$i] -match $pattern) {
    $insert += $i-1 #Record the position of the line before this one
  }
}

#Now loop the recorded array positions and insert the new text
$insert | Sort-Object -Descending | ForEach-Object { $file.insert($_,"NEWEMAILADDRESS") }

Set-Content $FileName $file
```

First open the file into an ArrayList, then loop over it. Each time you encounter the pattern, you can add the previous position into a separate array, `$insert`. Once the loop is done, you can then loop the positions in the `$insert` array and use them to add the text into the ArrayList.

Comment: I had the same setup but with a normal array, which makes it a lot more difficult. This is a great usage of an arraylist (something i've just picked up on earlier this week). Interesting read about arraylist in powershell : https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/09/28/create-arrays-for-performance-in-powershell.aspx

Comment: Awsome, Thank you for your help. I will look into learning more about arraylists.

Comment: You're welcome! Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped solve your problem

Comment: Isn't your insert going to change the position?  So if `$insert` is `3, 7`, and you insert a line at `3`, isn't item `7` going to change?  Won't the content have shifted from inserting at `3`?  I think you'll need to do `$insert | sort -descending | ForEach-Object [...]`.  That way you start inserting at the end and not the beginning.

Comment: @BaconBits yes, you're absolutely right. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a little state machine here. Note when you have found the correct section, but do not insert the line yet. Insert only at the next empty line (or the end of the file, if the section is the last in the file).

Haven't tested, but should look like this:

```
$FileName = "C:\temptest\testimport - Copy.txt"
$Pattern = "[[\]]Companyusers"  
$FileOriginal = Get-Content $FileName

[String[]] $FileModified = @() 

$inCompanyUsersSection = $false

Foreach ($Line in $FileOriginal)
{   
    if ($Line -match $pattern) 
    {
        $inCompanyUsersSection = $true
    }

    if ($inCompanyUsersSection -and $line.Trim() -eq "")
    {
        $FileModified += "NEWEMAILADDRESS"
        $inCompanyUsersSection = $false
    } 

    $FileModified += $Line
}

# Border case: CompanyUsers might be the last sction in the file
if ($inCompanyUsersSection)
{
    $FileModified += "NEWEMAILADDRESS"
} 

Set-Content $fileName $FileModified
```

Edit: If you don't want to use the "insert at the next empty line" approach, because maybe your section may in clude empty lines, you can also trigger the insert at the beginning of the next section (`$line.StartsWith("[")`). However that would complicate things because now you have to look two lines ahead which means you have to buffer one line before writing it out. Doable but ugly.

Comment: Hi Ttoni, thanks for your answer. Do you know what I need to do if I already have a blank space at the top (directly below [Companyusers]). And another blank space at the bottom? (This is the space that needs to be filled with the new email adress. I tested your script and it works, only the top is filled in instead of the bottom blank space. Thanks!

Comment: My algorithm currently monitors two events: 1. We are in the interesting section, 2. We hit a blank line. You could introduce a third event 3. We hit a new section. Just check each line for any of these conditions and then map out the appropiate actions (you have to defer writing blank lines until you know that no new section follows). Personally I would go another way: Read the file into a hashtable containing the sections as keys and an array of the section-lines as values. Then modify the section(s) you want and write them out again. Note this may modify the order though.